# Unit Testing Azure Functions and .csx Files

Tags: unit-testing, azure, visual-studio-2015, xunit, azure-functions

Azure Functions abstract plenty of dependencies like queue libraries and Azure Tables. So from a Unit Test dependencies mocking perspective, there is less coding effort (and accordingly less maintenance).

Assuming we are developing locally using Visual Studio 2015

- How can I unit test (not interested in integration test) a single Azure Function? Preferably in xUnit, however, any framework would do.
- How can I unit test a function in a .csx file in general?

Comment: One way would be to keep your unit tested code in a library, and reference/use it from csx.

Comment: Plus one to creating a class library and reference it from your Azure function. I did a brown bag about it, you can find the recording here https://youtu.be/G5tg1LkVr-E

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it stands, it's not really possible to unit test those files. For that reason (and a number of others), we have switched to a different model when developing Functions from Visual Studio, based on .cs and more standard .NET libraries. This makes a lot of things more 'normal' in Visual Studio. See [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs) for details.

Update: see also [Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0 in Unit Test for Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287628/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-4-1-1-0-in-unit-test-fo/46290387#46290387) relating to unit test projects.

Comment: Wow, that's big news! I definitely see the need for "normal" development, however, one concern I would have is that with ScriptCS we were able to focus on the core business logic and not have to worry about boilerplate code (no need for namespace, class, .csproj, .sln) and had the added benefit of compile on save. Hoping these features will be carried forward as much as possible.

Comment: The csx model will still be supported and used when using the Portal to do authoring. But for VS development, it's just not a very good fit.

Comment: @DavidEbbo is it safe to follow this approach until csx is moved away from?  http://126kr.com/article/6btiidvgril

Comment: Sorry, have not tried that so can't speak to it specifically.

Comment: For anyone else plugged in you can minimize your csx usage and unit test via a custom nuget package.  That is the direction we are going based on this information.

Comment: @DavidEbbo thanks, that is the best approach I hope. Intellisense, unit testing, all that good stuff you have in .cs is missing and it really hurts

Comment: @DavidEbbo i dont suppose you could provide an update or timeline for this?

Comment: @RobertLevy this [newer post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/) describes a different worflow, and that's the direction we're going toward in the coming months.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, recent release of Azure Functions project type is a great achievement! Though, talking about the OP question, the Unit Test projects still cannot reference the Azure Functions project correctly.

Comment: @Konstantin yes, there is an issue (being worked on), but it can still be done: https://github.com/vijayrkn-test/FunctionsProjectWithClassLib. Please open new question if you want to discuss further as it's outside the scope of this one.

Comment: @Konstantin Try upgrading `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to 1.0.2 (just released)

Comment: @DavidEbbo, wow thanks for such a quick response ) Personally I ended up moving all logic into a separate "Services" project (should be done from the start, I know) and used ILogger in that service class instead of TraceWriter to make testing easier. No, I do not need to start a separate question in this case )

Comment: Is it possible now to Unit Test  Azure functions written in .cs files using xUnit ?  does anyone have any sample code ?

Comment: @DavidEbbo Could you provide more info about how we should create the unit test for the csx files? was trying to follow the links but had no success  ( i downloaded  my project from the portal, just to clarify my steps..)

Comment: @USer22999299 as my answer explains, you can't unit test .csx files. You need to switch to the VS 2017 Functions project model instead.