# Unittest project Azure Functions could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json'

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, azure, azure-functions

I created a test project for a Function App as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46290387/3652378). The Http triggered Azure Function I wrote, uses dependency injection ([AzureFunctions.AutoFac](https://github.com/introtocomputerscience/azure-function-autofac-dependency-injection)) and looks like this:

```
[DependencyInjectionConfig(typeof(DependencyConfig))]
public static class CreateDeclarationsFunction
{
    [FunctionName("CreateDeclarationsFunction")]
    public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "CreateDeclarations")]HttpRequestMessage req,
        TraceWriter log,
        [Inject]IDeclarationDataService declarationDataService,
        [Inject]IClientDataService clientDataService)
    {
        log.Info("Http triggered function: CreateDeclarationsFunction  processed a request.");

        try
        {
            var clients = clientDataService.GetAll().ToList();

            foreach (var client in clients)
            {
                // Create and save new declaration for each client
                declarationDataService.CreateAndSaveNew(client.Id);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

And the unittest class (with Moq, Shouldly and NBuilder):

```
[TestClass]
public class CreateDeclarationsFunctionTest
{
    private Mock<IDeclarationDataService> _declarationDataService;
    private Mock<IClientDataService> _clientDataService;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _declarationDataService = new Mock<IDeclarationDataService>();
        _clientDataService = new Mock<IClientDataService>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateDeclarations_ReturnsOk()
    {
        // Arrange
        var clients = Builder<Client>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build();

        _declarationDataService.Setup(x => x.CreateAndSaveNew(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(Builder<Declaration>.CreateNew().Build);

        // Act > Exception by calling the Run method
        var result = CreateDeclarationsFunction.Run(CreateRequest(""), new TraceWriterStub(TraceLevel.Info),
            _declarationDataService.Object, _clientDataService.Object);

        // Assert
        // TODO
    }

    private static HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(string json)
    {
        // Just a mocked request
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost"),
            Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        return request;
    }
}
```

When I run this unittest, it gives an exception.

```
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters()
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection routes)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, Func`2 errorCreator)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, Exception exception)
   at FunctionApp.CreateDeclarationsFunction.Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, IDeclarationDataService declarationDataService, IClientDataService clientDataService)
   at FunctionApp.Tests.CreateDeclarationsFunctionTest.CreateDeclarations_ReturnsOk() in C:\TFS\...\FunctionApp.Tests\CreateDeclarationsFunctionTest.cs:line 63
Result Message: 
Test method FunctionApp.Tests.CreateDeclarationsFunctionTest.CreateDeclarations_ReturnsOk threw exception: 
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

The `FunctionApp` has 2 nested references to `Newtonsoft.Json (9.0.1)`, but none to version `6.0.0.0`.

`Dependencies` > `Nuget` > ``` Microsoft.NET``.Sdk.Functions (1.0.6) ``` > `Newtonsoft.Json (9.0.1)`

`Dependencies` > `Nuget` > `AzureFunctions.Autofac (2.0.0)` > `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs (2.1.0-beta4)` > `Newtonsoft.Json (9.0.1)`

The test project has a reference to the `FunctionApp` project. The exception is only shown when unit testing and not when its running (and being invoked from the browser). 
Does anybody have a solution for upper exception? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I found out that the `System.IO.FileLoadException` occurs when returning `req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);`

When returning `req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);` instead, it does not give the mentioned exception.

Comment: Do you have an app.config file with a binding redirect for Newtonsoft.Json in your test project? A proper binding redirect there (similar to this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/0b4277b38a89527d21ec9ddd125897013d2542be/test/WebJobs.Script.Tests/app.config#L25-L28) might help

Comment: @FabioCavalcante, indeed that was the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think because of the way I setup the test project (initially `.NET standard` and then converted the target framework manually to `.NET Framework 4.6.1` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287628/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-4-1-1-0-in-unit-test-fo/46290387#46290387)), no `app.config` file is generated in the test project. Furthermore, I think that such a test project setup does not automatically generate binding redirects for nuget packages when updating the version of a nuget package partly in the solution.

As [@FabioCavalcante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1177901/fabio-cavalcante) mentioned, I manually had to add an `app.config` file to the test project and put a binding redirect for `Newtonsoft.Json`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```